# Error while passing a json field in graphql mutation with django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, graphql

the below code is to update the "personalize" field in the user model (django), which is a json field, not sure how to pass it has an argument to the mutation

```
class AddPersonalization(graphene.Mutation):
    ok = graphene.Boolean()

    class Arguments():
        user_id = graphene.Int(required=True)
        personalize = graphene.JSONString(required=True)

    def mutate(self, user_id, personalize):
        try:
            get_user_model().objects.filter(id=user_id).update(personalize=personalize)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            raise Exception("User doesn't exist")
        return AddPersonalization(ok=True)
```

graphql query

```
mutation{
  addPersonalization(userId :285 ,personalize:["sample1", "sample2"]  )
  {
    ok
  }
}
```

error response :

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Argument \"personalize\" has invalid value [\"sample1\", \"sample2\"].\nExpected type \"JSONString\", found [\"sample1\", \"sample2\"].",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 47
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are sending and array of strings, rather than the JSONString object.

```
JSON.stringify(Object that you are sending).
```